# Spring security, session is created without logging-in after session timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have created a default form-login authentication and below is my configuration.

```
<!-- Empty filter chain for the login page -->
<http pattern="/rest/login" security="none" />
<http pattern="/install/license/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <request-cache ref="authenticationRequestCache" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/rest/login?error=denied" />
    <form-login login-page="/rest/login"    
        authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/rest/login?error" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/devices" access="denyAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/devices/**" access="denyAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/super/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/cavirinRest/*" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/rest/login?error=sessionExpired" 
        session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/rest/login" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</http>
```

Authentication works fine as expected, but recently i added session-timeout to the application. My application polls server for every 5 seconds, hence the default time out does not work. I googled and found below solution with filter and implemented it.

from web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>XhrSessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.cavirin.security.filter.XhrSessionTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>XhrSessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<session-config>
    <!-- Disables URL-based sessions (no more 'jsessionid' in the URL using Tomcat) -->
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session != null) {
        logger.trace("doFilterInternal(): session object is not null.");

        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(120); //2 mins for testing //set max inactive interval to 30 mins

        // if requestURI is not null
        if (request.getRequestURI() != null) {

            logger.trace("doFilterInternal(): request.getRequestURI() : {} ", request.getRequestURI());

            String ajaxHeader = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
            logger.trace("doFilterInternal(): ajaxHeader : {} ", ajaxHeader);

            //if it is an AJAX call
            if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(ajaxHeader)) {
                logger.trace("doFilterInternal(): An AJAX call, set the last access time, if not already set.");
                Long lastAccess = (Long) session.getAttribute(AJAX_DATA_LAST_ACCESS_TIME);

                if (lastAccess == null) {
                    logger.trace("doFilterInternal(): Last access time is null, set current time as lastAccess time.");
                    lastAccess = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    session.setAttribute(AJAX_DATA_LAST_ACCESS_TIME, lastAccess);
                } else {
                    logger.trace("doFilterInternal(): max interval: {} -- lastAccess: {} -- currentTimeMillis: {} ",
                        + session.getMaxInactiveInterval(), lastAccess, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    if (((session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastAccess)) < 0) {
                        logger.debug("doFilterInternal(): session should be invalidated as inative time execeeded.");
                        session.invalidate();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                logger.trace("doFilterInternal(): Not an AJAX call.");
                session.removeAttribute(AJAX_DATA_LAST_ACCESS_TIME);
            }
        }
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Timeout also works fine, but once time out occurs, my ajax request (i see it on chrome - developer tools, network tab) gets 302 status as it is redirected to another page. i.e my log-in page with session timeout error message. I don't click on anything and I leave it for another 2mins (i set 2mins timeout for testing), again I see a log message saying that "session expired" and redirected to log-in. I could see there a new jsessionid is created after session expiration

```
RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showLogin(Model model,
                              @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String errorStr,
                              HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.trace("Returning login page view.");

    String pageToBeLoaded = "rest/login" ;

    System.out.println("showLogin(): errorStr: " + errorStr);

    if (errorStr != null) {

        if (errorStr.equalsIgnoreCase("sessionExpired")) {
            logger.debug("showLogin(): error: sessionExpired ");
            System.out.println("showLogin(): error: sessionExpired");
            model.addAttribute("error", "Session expired. Please log in again.");
        } else if (errorStr.equalsIgnoreCase("denied")) {
            logger.debug("showLogin(): error: denied ");
            System.out.println("showLogin(): error: denied");
            model.addAttribute("error", "Access is denined. This page is for SUPER user only.");
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("error", getErrorMessage(request, "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"));
            System.out.println("showLogin(): error: " + getErrorMessage(request, "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"));
        }
    } 
    return new ModelAndView(pageToBeLoaded);
}
```

I know that I did not stop polling server after timeout, so it polls again and again, But 1) how the session is created without logging-in to the application?

Also, 2) I'm not getting session timeout error message, as it is redirected to this page once and again it goes to log-in page. I'm not able to hold this error message until user is logging in again.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much reading about spring security and its related stuff, came to know that 
1) session is created by default (http config, if-required) and once session timed-out, it will automatically redirect to a given url on session-management of invalid-session-url and creates another session. I observed this behavior in the spring-security debug log, which states that, session invalidated, creating another session if required.
2) Once the timed-out session is invalidated, it redirects to invalid-session-url; but my ajax keeps polling from the same page, the another session is created and looking for authentication to access my secure web page, hence redirection happens to my log-in page, but this time no session time out error.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent spring security from creating another session on the session invalidation ? To make it just redirect to a given url on session-management of invalid-session-url...

Answer (score 1):

You figured out correctly.

Let me explain it.

> Session is created by default

Yes It is called as ROLE_ANONYMOUS.

By default if there is No session(No cookie with JSESSIONID) it will create a session with Role = ROLE_ANONYMOUS, If already authenticated it will not create new session.

And hence ROLE_ANONYMOUS is a Un-authenticated user.

permitAll includes ANONYMOUS user also. ANONYMOUS user will be permitted to access that resource.

Just try this. authorize admin resources to ANONYMOUS user like this

```
.antMatchers("/app/admin/*").hasRole("ANONYMOUS")
```

Then admin resources can only be accessed without login. If logged in with admin credential and tried to access you will get 403 error(Forbidden).

UNAUTHENTICATED user is a ANONYMOUS user, he will also get a session to identify him, hence his session also gets invalidated after timeout hence it redirects to a page configured in session managements expiredUrl.

He is the only one user who can not reach AuthenticationSuccessHandler